# Start outSide scroll after edittext scroll finished

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I've tried every simple examples on stackoverflow but nothing can solve my problem. Here's my question

I have `ScrollView` in `activity` and I have `scrollbars="vertical"` option `editText` inside `ScrollView`.

I want to scroll outside `scrollview`'s scroll after inside `edittext` scroll finish, like on top of the `edittext` scroll or bottom of the `edittext` scroll

I thought that it can be done with view catchs `scroll lisetener` but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. Do you want to put scrollable edittext inside a scrollview??

Comment: I'm sorry my explanation is not enough. I mean I have activity and in that activity i have one scroll view. and then inside the scroll view I have one edit text that can scroll(Fix sized view but contents can be infinite). Then now is my question. i clicked edittext and put lots of texts inside it and then edittext scroll run. after i finished texting inside edittext i scrolled edittext contents to the top. But after this scrolling i want to directly scroll with outside scroll view's scroll. ( it mean edittext has focus to scroll and i want to move focus and scrollable to outside scroll view)

Comment: I think if i know the timing of edittext scroll finish. then i think i can move the scroll event and focus to scrollview with dispatchTouchEvent like this

Comment: means without touching out side the edit text you want the scrollview to scroll.

Comment: yes not exactly but mean same, in my app the edittext size is too big so there's no enough view to scroll outside, so i think user scroll only edittext but when it has focus, soft keyboard isn't close and no way to scroll outside but only use hardware back button.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sample code hope it works for you.

In XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aa8822"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aa8822"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>  
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Put some more view so the scroll view scroll works.

Now in your activity-

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);

        edt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (v.getId() == R.id.edt) {
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```